# Is there a way to format numbers' font when surfing web using Chrome/Firefox browser?

Tags: fonts, automation, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

I love to see numbers in `Georgia` font and would love to see them auto-formatted into that font! If you know such tools, please share!

*Update*

I want just numbers to be formatted while other texts remain as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the script http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/93665

Answer (score 2):

If you're handy with [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/748/), you could write a script to do that.  (There may already be a script for this, do some checking around)

Comment: Can you give me some specific `greasemonkey script` to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of one.